# How does a ContentProvider know what type of data to serve

Tags: android

I'm wondering how a content provider differentiates between a sql data query and a ParcelFileDescripter request.

I have implemented:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
Log.d(TAG,filename);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://com.xxxxxxxx.pdfprovider/" + file.getPath()),      "application/pdf");
startActivity(i);
```

This calls:

```
ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException
```

in the content provider subclass.

How does the provider know that he needs to open a file?

Comment: Classes that support `#setDataAndType(..)` as good, upstanding, Android citizens, will attempt to fetch your `Uri` using [ContentResolver#openInputStream(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream%28android.net.Uri%29), which in turn will talk to your provider.